# How to extract string betweeen double quotes using NSRegularExpression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Hi I have to extract data between double quotes.If my string is:

```
"""rach"",""jkdj""","""abc"",13","123,4.45,""19""","3.33,""123"",""2.221"""
```

My strings are here data from CSV files.I need to extract data between the double quotes.I try to accomplish this with NSRegularExpression.

My regex pattern is :

```
NSString *exp=@"\".+\""
```

I again get the entire string as the match. Where am I going wrong? How can I get `""rach"", ""jkdj""` and `""abc"", 13` and so on...

Thank you @Derek.Your reply helped me a great deal.My data is wierd coz I'm just trying various combinations of data into a CSV file.The entry into the CSV file can be of numerous combinations.There may or may not be commas or double quotes in the data itself.What I want is just data between double quotes( not a problem if the double quotes themselves are included ).I hope I'm able to explain what I want.With your help, I have written a regex for this string.

```
NSString *exp=@"[^,]\"*[^,]*,(([^,]\"*?,*?)*|(\"*[^,]*\"*)*)";
```

Here exp is my regex.

```
"""pav"",""ani""","""abc"",13","123,4.45,""19""","3.33,""123"",""2.221"""
```

And this is my string.The first double quote has ""pav"",""ani"".The second has ""abc"",13.The third has 123,4.45,""19"".Fourth has 3.33,""123"",""2.221"".So I need each of these as a match with the double quotes included wouldn't be an issue.

I ought to get the following as each match:

```
"""pav"",""ani"""
"""abc"",13"
"123,4.45,""19"""
"3.33,""123"",""2.221"""
```

But I get this with the regex that I mentioned.

```
2013-09-20 11:09:04.398 regexPractice[13968] match: """pav"",""ani"""
2013-09-20 11:09:04.425 regexPractice[13968] match: """abc"",13"
2013-09-20 11:09:04.434 regexPractice[13968] match: "123,4.45
2013-09-20 11:09:04.442 regexPractice[13968] match: ""19""","3.33
2013-09-20 11:09:04.454 regexPractice[13968] match: ""123"",""2.221"""
```

I can see that the regex needs a slight change but I can't find where.

Any clues? TIA

Comment: regex tag says: "Regular expressions (often shortened to &quot;regex&quot;) are a declarative language used for pattern matching within strings. Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.Regular expressions (often shortened to &quot;regex&quot;) are a declarative language used for pattern matching within strings. Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Answer (score 1):

I found the following seems to work:

```
\"\"[^"]+\"\"
```

The logic is quote, quote, any character that is not a quote (more than one times), quote, quote.

You could put brackets around the any character that is not a quote (more than one times) part to capture the inner part if you want:

```
\"\"([^"]+)\"\"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.I see that I get ""rach"" ""jkdj"" as two matches.What I desire is ""rach"",""jkdj"" as a single match, which is in between a pair of double quotes.                                          TIA

Comment: Thankyou @Beppe. I'm asking this in the context of Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

OK.. maybe this is what you want:

```
\"\"\".+?\"\"\"
```

.+? - is lazy... I was always wondering how to use lazy operators.

But there seems to be something weird about how your data is defined - I was looking for triple quotes.

Here is the full line:

"""rach"",""jkdj""","""abc"",13","123,4.45,""19""","3.33,""123"",""2.221"""

Manually splitting using sets of triple quotes:

"""rach"",""jkdj"""

"""abc"",13","123,4.45,""19"""

"3.33,""123"",""2.221""" -- this one doesn't have triple quote at start